# Self-contained infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

What do you call an infinite sequence like this? $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}: \forall a=(x_i,x_{i+1},x_{i+2},...,x_{i+j}) \exists b=(x_k, x_{k+1},x_{k+2},...,x_{k+j});i \not=k:a=b$

For example, the 2-adic valuation of 2n, https://oeis.org/A001511

In other words, every portion of the sequence has a copy of itself in the sequence. In fact, every portion would have an infinite amount of copies of itself. I thought this would be called a fractal sequence, but it is not the case.

Comment: Seems to me that this doesn't have an accepted name so far.
But here's a piece of advice : I've once been told that the core of mathematics is to find the right definitions. If this type of sequences is of any importance for you and if you like the name "fractral sequence", you can just _define_ the notion of fractal sequences to be these sequences you just described, and then work with that. 

The names and definitions of objects in mathematics are nothing absolute : we just decide on those that makes our work clearer, and some just happen to be so useful that they become comonplace.

Comment: This may be the case that it doesn't have a name. However, it seems basic enough where I'd expect it to have a name. Unfortunately, "fractal sequences" have already been taken and has very little to do with my definition.